# Trying to run a simple insert query but its not executing (mapreduce process not being initialized,reference below)...really new to hive

Tags: hive, insert, bigdata

```
[hive» INSERT INTO tt (D, subject, T) VALUES ('11-09-1999', 'Math', '11am-12pm'); 
Query ID = princemehta_20230308174407_06bb913d-1dcd-42cf-9fd6-53bcf6ab1848 
Total jobs = 3 
Launching Job out of 3 [Number of reduce tasks determined at compile time: 1 
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes): 
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number> 
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers: 
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number> 
In order fO set a constant number of reducers. 
  set mapreduce.job.reduces=<number> 
starting Job job_1678277480407._0001, Tracking URL = http://localhost:8088/proxy/application_1678277480407_0001/ Kill Command = /usr/local/opt/hadoop/libexec/bin/mapredjob
-kill job_1678277480407_0001
```

When every I try to run a simple insert query, the job is not executing instead it gets stuck, at the last line -kill job_1678277480407_0001. I'm not running this query in cloudera but on macos terminal. I think the problem is the engine (mr,spar,tez) as i'm able to run select * query.....

Comment: first of all, pls dont post images. Secondly, pls post more details. your image is not giving any error or any indication of errors.

Comment: I have updated, thank you.

Comment: can you post error msg if any pls?

Comment: nope no error message.

Comment: but after terminating it shows...  killing job with: job_1678419857860_0002
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 0; number of reducers: 0
2023-03-10 10:00:45,255 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
Ended Job = job_1678419857860_0002 with errors
Error during job, obtaining debugging information...
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Stage-Stage-1:  HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec